# Error with creating a csv file in python: Operation not permitted

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to create an empty csv file in python (2.7) but see the following error. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
>>> tutorial_out = open('tutorial.csv', 'wb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'tutorial.csv'
```

Comment: You likely do not have write permission in the directory you are trying to write to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue, you probably don't have permission to write in that directory.

Solution: Modify permission of that directory or run as root.